# What type should be in FuriaError variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
 async Furia(URL) {
    try {
      const Res = await fetch(URL);
      const Furia0= await Res.json();
      return Furia0;
    } catch (FuriaError) { //type FuriaError?
      return FuriaError;
    }
  }
```

What type should be in FuriaError variable?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be [not possible](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8677#issuecomment-220385124) with TypeScript.

> We don't allow type annotations on catch clauses because there's really no way to know what type an exception will have. You can throw objects of any type and system generated exceptions (such as out of memory exception) can technically happen at any time. Even if we had a Java-like notion of throws annotations it is not clear that we could ever really rely on them. (And, it is also not clear that they work all that well in Java, but that's another discussion.)

Also look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9999), where all related github issues are linked.